# Linq Sorting not working as expected. Pretty confusing

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have been juggling around for a very basic thing here. So I have a class here like this:

```
public class LinqItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Gifts { get; set; }
    public int FirstYear { get; set; }
    public double LargestYear { get; set; }
    public int MonthGiving { get { return Gifts > 5 ? Gifts : 0; } }

}
```

I have a code which returns the collection of LinqItem type. Here is the code.

```
List<LinqItem> items = LoadCSV();
//some code to produce my collection. NO problem till this point, so I don't think LoadCSV function is required at all.
List<LinqItem> newItems = items
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.LargestYear)
    .ThenBy(c => c.AccountNumber)
    .ThenBy(c => c.Year).ToList();
```

Now, in the above line, what I am trying to do is sort the collection first by LargestYear Descending, and then Order by Account Number Ascending and then by Year Ascending.

After sorting, I am creating a CSV file with the output. The whole function looks like this:

```
private void CreateCSV(string csvFile)
{
    List<LinqItem> items = LoadCSV(); 
    List<LinqItem> newItems = items.OrderByDescending(c => c.LargestYear).ThenBy(c => c.AccountNumber).ThenBy(c => c.Year).ToList();

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    int index = 1;
    foreach (LinqItem i in newItems)
    {
        text.AppendLine(i.AccountNumber + "," + i.Year + "," + i.Value + "," + i.Gifts + "," + index + "," + i.FirstYear + "," + i.LargestYear);
        index++;
    }

    StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(csvFile);
    w.Write(text.ToString());
    w.Close();
}
```

Now, so far, pretty simple. But the problems when in CSV, the Largest Year values for different account number is same. Ideally, I would expect that if the Largest year is same, then the items will be sorted on the basis of Account Number and year. But it is not happening. See the following screenshot:

[image: Sorting Screenshot]

In the screenshot, Column A is Account Number, Column B is Year, and Column G is Largest Year. And in an ideal world, and with my Sorting assumptions, I would assume 101864 (Cell A6303) should come before 103816 (cell A6297) because I sorted Account Number as ascending. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: A short example of the data you're processing would help in knowing why the sort is giving odd results.

Comment: Have you tried debug the code, to see what you get in the `newItems` list? The sorting code looks ok, so I suspect the peroblem is in CSV parsing/reading/writing or maybe you are just looking to the wrong file result. BTW Excel can also sort the data, so be sure it hasn't.

Comment: `LargestYear` is a `double`. Perhaps the values are not exactly equal and they are sorted on differences in the `double` value that you do not see because you do not inspect all 15 digits? E.g. `1.000000000000000 < 1.000000000000001` but you don't notice because to you `1 = 1`.

Comment: Excel does some strange things with rounding occasionally - click the cells to ensure the values are what you expect as Excel will round values for display purposes

Comment: Not only Excel possibly has rounding issues, so does the double datatype. This can influence the sorting in LINQ, before we even get to the CSV. Can you give information about the expected range of values in LargestYear? So you could possibly trim it down to a smaller data type before sorting.

Comment: Why is a property `LargestYear` a `double` at all? Maybe you could use a more appropriate type like `DateTime`, `int` or `TimeSpan`. What is it's purpose?

Comment: Sorry for confusion guys. Excel comes into picture only after CSV is produced. I have checked the manual output opening in notepad as text format and I can see there are no rounding issues. @Alex, I will debug and re-assure myself I am not doing anything wrong. FYI, sorry for my odd response, this small thing is driving me crazy. Since I am an avid Excel guy, so I have already gone through all the possibilities about what Excel can cause. So strange.

Comment: @Tim, LargestYear means the amount largest in a year. The title looks shaky, and the amount can be a decimal value. Hence it is double.

Comment: @Vikas: then try to use `decimal`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, agree, you shouldn't `decimal` is the right choice here.

Comment: Ok, resolved. Thanks guys for the heads up. It was actually a precision problem and since I was using like tons of Linq processing, it was difficult to find out as these double values were generated at the run time. Thanks guys. I am not sure how to close the question? Anyone wants to add the precision problem as answer and I will select that answer as correct answer? Thanks a lot for helping me out though. Cheers!!!